# objective-c frameworks - Dynamic Library Install Name

Tags: objective-c, frameworks

I'm new to objective-c & osx architecture.  I started playing with building a framework and then using it.  I followed this great [tutorial](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2010/12/28/a-visual-guide-to-creating-an-embeddable-framework-for-mac-osx).

During the tutorial, I had to set the framework's target's **Dynamic Library Install Name** to `@rpath/MyFramework.framework/Versions/A/MyFramework.`  My understanding is that **@rpath** will expand to the loader's (consumer's) **run-path search paths**.

It seems as if the responsibility of loading the framework is split between the framework author and the consumer author.  Could someone please explain why the author of the framework needs to be concerned with the consumer's run-path search path?  For example, if the framework-author set the **Dynamic Library Install Name** to point to some random directory (instead of **@rpath**) how would the client be able to consume the framework?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a lot on how the framework is being used.   And it's important to remember that the framework construct has existed for a long time on the platform.

For a system framework, such as the ones that Apple creates, you're going to be quite happy that they keep the frameworks in a known location.   In those cases, the paths that they use are fixed for the OS, and it guarantees that you don't accidentally load the wrong one.  Further, as indicated in the Framework documentation, these frameworks are loaded only once on the machine, regardless of how many times they are used (see [Apple:What Are Frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WhatAreFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002303-BBCEIJFI)) .   The benefit here is performance and it is for both the code and the resources in many cases.

Due to the recent move to randomize framework locations,and Apple's comments in the release notes that "Mountain Lion randomly relocates the kernel, kexts, and system frameworks at system boot," it certainly appears they're still sharing these resources, and thus still gaining from this benefit.

For embedded frameworks, the situation is a lot more tedious, and Apple has moved through a variety of methods over the years to make it easier to find frameworks wherever they may be.   Due, again, to the shared nature, it would make sense for Applications which share common library requirements to share them on the machine, both for purposes of efficiency, and to make sure they're at the same version if they're sharing data.   So, for example, if you have two separate apps that use the same framework to work with shared data, you might put the shared framework in `/Library/Frameworks` and have both apps explicitly look for that, making sure that some other (possibly older) version of the framework, that has been loaded by another App, is not used instead.

In the end, there's a lot of flexibility for the Framework producer and consumer the way that it currently works.   It means that the developer can decide to share a framework, include a private copy of the framework, or even do both, depending upon whether the framework exists on the machine or not.  However, the price for that flexibility is the complexity that we have today.

Another example of a reason you might not want to use `@rpath` specifically is for tightly-linked embedded frameworks (yes, people embed frameworks within other frameworks).   In these cases, you don't know where the first framework is loaded, but you want to put the embedded framework inside of it, so that they stay together.   In this case `@loader_path` is relative to the code that is loading it, so that your plug-in's framework can find its resources correctly.

In answer to your specific example about somebody setting the **Dynamic Library Install Name** 
 to a "random" location.  In this case, you'd have to know that location.   There might be many reasons for somebody doing this, such as wanting to discourage reuse by other programs, or because there are large resources within the framework that should only be installed in a known shared location.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.  A follow up question, which I'll post separately.

Comment: Best explanation I found so far, thanks!